# Flutter groupBy date: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list like this:

```
List<ProductModel> productList = [
    ProductModel(name: "Oranges", date: "2023-05-01"),    
    ProductModel(name: "Apples", date: "2023-05-01"),
    ProductModel(name: "Kiwis", date: "2023-03-01"),
];
```

I would like to group the items by date using `groupBy` and display it in `Widget build` as so:

```
2023-05-01:
Oranges
Apples

2023-03-01:
Kiwis
```

Currently, I am getting the following error: `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.`  and I can't seem to fix it.

My code is below.

```
class ProductListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _ProductListPageState();
}

class _ProductListPageState extends State<ProductListPage> {
  late StreamController<int> _postsController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _postsController = new StreamController();
    getProducts();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getProducts() {
    Fetch.getProdcuts().then((value) => {
      _postsController.add(1);
      
      List<ProductModel> productList = [];

      for (var item in value!) {

         final encode = json.encode(item.toJson());
         final product = ProductModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(encode));
         productList.add(product);
      }

      //I get the error here:
      var groupByDate = groupBy(productList, (obj) => obj?.date.substring(0, 10));

    });
  }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        //Build method here
    }

class ProductModel extends Object {
  String? name;
  String? date;

  ProductModel({this.name, this.date});

  ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json["name"];
    date = json["date"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'name': name,
    'date': date,
  };
}
```

This is what I also tried but I am getting various errors:

`var groupByDate = groupBy(value!.toList(), value.map((obj) => ProductModel.fromJson(obj)).toList());`

-> Error: `The argument type 'List<ProductModel>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(ProductModel)'.`

`var groupByDate = groupBy(value!.toList(), (obj) => obj?.date.substring(0, 10).toList());`

-> Error: `The getter 'date' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.`

Now I am basically out of ides. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
void getProducts() {
  Fetch.getProdcuts().then((value) {
    _postsController.add(1);

    var productList = value
        .map((obj) => ProductModel.fromJson(obj as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();

    var groupByDate = groupBy(
        productList, (obj) => obj.date?.substring(0, 10) ?? '');

    
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer! Same error here - I get `The getter 'date' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.`  when assigning the groupByDate  variable.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what I was missign at the end. I had to define the `obj` as `ProductModel` here:

`(obj) => (obj! as ProductModel).date`

Full working code below:

```
class ProductListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _ProductListPageState();
}

class _ProductListPageState extends State<ProductListPage> {
  late StreamController<int> _postsController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _postsController = new StreamController();
    getProducts();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getProducts() {
    Fetch.getProdcuts().then((value) => {
      _postsController.add(1);
      
      List<ProductModel> productList = [];

      for (var item in value!) {

         final encode = json.encode(item.toJson());
         final product = ProductModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(encode));
         productList.add(product);
      }

      var groupByDate = groupBy(productList, (obj) => (obj! as ProductModel).date);

    });
  }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        //Build method here
    }

class ProductModel extends Object {
  String? name;
  String? date;

  ProductModel({this.name, this.date});

  ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json["name"];
    date = json["date"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'name': name,
    'date': date,
  };
}
```